# How to listen for changes in documents scroll Height in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using next js for my web application, I am writing a code that would get a percentage from a response and it would convert it to the height of the document and scroll it automatically. Everything works fine, until I refresh the page, I get an error saying document is not defined.

```js
//postProgress is the response, I am listenining for loading, as the document loads, it becomes bigger. 
useEffect(() => {
        if(postdata.isLoading == false && postProgress != null) {
            const heightWin = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            var offset = postProgress / 100;
            var offsetScroll = offset * heightWin;
            window.scrollTo(0,offsetScroll);
            console.log(heightWin,offsetScroll)
        }
    },[postinfo.isLoading, postdata.isLoading,postProgress,document.documentElement.scrollHeight]); // I need to listen to changes to the document scroll height here.
```

How do I solve this issue, or is there a better way to listen for scroll change?

Comment: if you want to keep track of your scroll states or any other global state, I prefer to keep them on the state managements such as Redux for react applications.

Comment: `document` will not normally be available outside of `useEffect` when using Next.js. Your React code is being rendered on the server side, where there is no `document` (or `window`) object to look up. Putting `scrollHeight` in the dependency array is also pointless since changes to its value are happening outside React and won't trigger an effect. You should use a [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) if you want to track changes to scroll position.

Comment: What @lawrence-witt said is correct,try loading your components with `next/dynamic` with SSR set to false.

Comment: Let me try that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` as a dependency to `useEffect` and the property `documentElement` cannot be accessed as `document` will be undefined when executing SSR:

```
[postinfo.isLoading, postdata.isLoading,postProgress,document.documentElement.scrollHeight]);
```

I would recommend you modify to something like the following:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const handleResize = (e) => {
        const heightWin = window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        console.info(window.innerHeight, heightWin);

        // do whatever
        ...
      }

      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize); // ideally you need to throttle this event

      // fire on first render if needed
      handleResize();

      // cleanup this component
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      };
  },[postinfo.isLoading, postdata.isLoading,postProgress]);
```